# How to place two bootstrap cards next to each other

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to place the two cards next to each other (horizontally) but currently they are vertically aligned. That is I want to place the Heading 1 card next to Heading 2 card even though I used some margin it shift only in the same place horizontally not vertically.

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Heading 1</h5>
            <p class="card-text">some text</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">a button</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Heading 2</h5>
            <p class="card-text">some text</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">a button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap them both inside a div and use "Display: flex".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap’s grid to achieve this:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Heading 1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">some text</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">a button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;>
        <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Heading 2</h5>
          <p class="card-text">some text</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">a button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , i am new to front end so can you help me with one more that how can i change the height and apply padding ?

Comment: @Mayank you can give height as per your requirement. and if you want to align cards to the center of the grid, use `class="d-flex justify-content-center"`. Please consider accepting my answer if it had helped you out

Comment: One more question how can i apply borders to cards?
<span class="border border-dark"></span>
I used this but it coeverd like the top left corner of the card (in height and width) even after increasing the hight and width the right side and the lower side is borderless